# Обработать Ajax при покидании страницы unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Не могу отправить дынные через Ajax при покидании страницы

```
//Ловим покидание со страницы
$(window).on("unload", function (e) {

//Собираем данные с imput
$('input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('id')) {
        //console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        new_input[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
    }
});

//Проверяем есть ли изменения в input
if (JSON.stringify(old_input) !== JSON.stringify(new_input)) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/admin/ajax/add',
        data: {action: action, data: JSON.stringify(new_input)},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('fff');
        }
    });
}

});
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: А где у Вас объявляется переменная old_input?

Comment: Чуть выше есть код там просто все в коментах поэтому не стал выкладывать. Суть в том что если поменять событие c $(window).on("unload", function (e) { на $('test').on('click', function () { и отловить код то все работает